# inverse D operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had a doubt about the property of $$ D^{-1} $$ operator.

Is $$ \frac{1}{D-1}\frac{1}{D^{2}}h(x)= \frac{1}{D^{2}}\frac{1}{D-1}h(x) $$

Does this hold true for any

$$ \frac{1}{f(D)}\frac{1}{g(D)}h(x)= \frac{1}{g(D)}\frac{1}{f(D)}h(x) $$

Comment: An operator commutes with its powers, as their composition is associative. In a space where the listed operators have inverses (i.e. the above makes sense), the claim should follow from that and the uniqueness of the inverse. BTW you are using $f$ in two (hopefully) unrelated meanings.

Comment: The only problem of this operator is, that it doesn't commute with its inverse. Because the derivative *swallows* the constant, it's $D^{-1}D=DD^{-1}+C$. If you avoid that, it should be fine.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is it okay to first find $$ \frac{1}{g(D)}h(x) $$ and then operate $$\frac{1}{f(D)}$$ on the answer obtained and vice versa while finding the particular integral $$ \frac{1}{f(D)}\frac{1}{g(D)}h(x)= \frac{1}{g(D)}\frac{1}{f(D)}h(x) $$

Answer (score 0):

Using operator $D$ in rational expressions is an abuse of notation, but can be easily formalized with laplace transform. What you write as $D$ is actually the $s$ in laplace transform, so

$$\frac{1}{D^2}f(x)$$
actually means
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \frac{F(s)}{s^2}$$

However, you should realize that differentiation
$$Df(x)$$
transforms into
$$sF(s)-f(0)$$
where $F(s)=\mathcal{L} f(x)$, so the initial conditions have to be respected. If your transformation doesn't change these silently omitted initial conditions, it's ok, because the argument $s$ in the Laplace transform is just a scalar and commutes with itself.

Comment: I wanted to know if the form I've given above applies while finding the particular integral $$\frac{1}{f(D)}\frac{1}{g(D)}h(x)= \frac{1}{g(D)}\frac{1}{f(D)}h(x) $$ That is, whether it is ok to find $$ \frac{1}{g(D)}h(x) $$ and then operate $$\frac{1}{f(D)}$$ on the answer obtained and vice versa.

Comment: @Curious That's exactly why I introduced the Laplace transform. Because $s$ is just an ordinary variable, it's $1/f(s)1/g(s)=1/g(s)1/f(s)$. The only problem are the initial conditions. When you apply $1/g(D)$, you use some initial condition to integrate, and when you apply $1/f(D)$ an appropriate initial condition must be selected to operate on the intermediate result. This must be done correctly to get the same solution. If you leave the integration constants undetermined, it should be fine.